# No idea what wallet site, or password(s) but has the old computer

Tags: wallet

My friend was paid out in bitcoin approx 2 years ago, she has no idea what wallet site, password(s) but has the old computer still. Is there a way to find enough data to recover her Btc? She is and was clueless about btc, wallets, etc...  I practiced looking on my computer after briefly searching the net and couldn't find a wallet.dat file. Went back to work searching the net and found this site first thing.

Comment: There are simply too many possible wallets, and too many of them would leave no trace on the computer to be able to narrow this down. Your best bet would be to try all the common ones such as Bitcoin Core, Blockchain.info, electrum, armory, multibit, etc.

Comment: That's what i'm afraid of.  I'll have her look through her email but I can already hear her voice saying she doesn't have/use that email anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Is there a way to find enough data to recover her BTC?**

Probably not.

If she didn't make a note of her password and forgot it then she almost certainly didn't make a safe backup of her private-key or seed-phrase either. You could ask her about that though

> **She is and was clueless about btc, wallets, etc**

That often means people lose their BTC.

> **My friend was paid out in bitcoin approx 2 years ago**

Her best chance would be to find email or other correspondence relating to that event. If she can remember who "paid out" and why, maybe she can get back in touch with them and hope that they recall where the BTC were sent - they may at least have a record of the receiving address and that will help her find out whether there is still any unspent BTC associated with that address.